# Integral representation of the power of a positive number via the gamma function.

Tags: gamma-function

Let $s\in(0,1)$. I managed to prove that
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\lambda^s}=\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\int_0^\infty t^{s-1}e^{-\lambda t}dt,\qquad\lambda>0.
\end{align}
It directly follows from the definition of the Gamma function as
\begin{align}
\Gamma(x)=\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}e^{-x} dx, x>0
\end{align}
and a change of variables. Now I try to prove that
\begin{align}
\lambda^s=\frac{1}{|\Gamma(-s)|}\int_0^\infty t^{-(s+1)}(1-e^{-\lambda t})dt,\qquad\lambda>0.
\end{align}
But I'm stuck.

**Attempt:**
We can define the gamma function for $-s$ as
\begin{align}
\Gamma(-s):=\frac{-1}{s}\Gamma(1-s):=-\frac{\lambda^{1-s}}{s}\int_0^\infty t^{-s}e^{-\lambda t}
\end{align}
I tried Integration-by-parts,
\begin{align} \int u dv=uv-\int v du.
\end{align}
I chose $u=t^{-s}$ and $dv=-\lambda e^{-\lambda t}$. But $uv=t^{-s}e^{-\lambda t}$ which diverges as $t$ goes to zero.

Answer (score 1):

Fix some $s\in(0,1)$, and consider the function defined for $\lambda>0$ given by
$$
f(\lambda)
:=
\lambda^s
+
\frac 1{\Gamma(-s)}\int_0^\infty t^{-s}(1-e^{-\lambda t})\;\frac{dt}t\ .
$$
Then $f(0)=0$, and
$$
\begin{aligned}
f'(\lambda)
&=
s\lambda^{s-1}
+
\frac 1{\Gamma(-s)}\int_0^\infty t^{1-s}e^{-\lambda t}\;\frac{dt}t
\\
&=
s\left(
\lambda^{s-1}
-
\frac 1{-s\Gamma(-s)}\int_0^\infty t^{1-s}e^{-\lambda t}\;\frac{dt}t
\right)
\\
&=
s\left(
\frac 1{\lambda^{\color{blue}{1-s}}}
-
\frac 1{\Gamma(\color{blue}{1-s})}
\int_0^\infty t^{\color{blue}{1-s}}e^{-\lambda t}\;\frac{dt}t
\right)
\\
&=0
\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
by using the first relation from the posted question (for $\color{blue}{1-s}\in(0,1)$ instead of $s$). So $f$ is identically zero.

$\square$

Answer (score 0):

You have $$|\Gamma(-s)|=\frac{1}{s}\Gamma(1-s)=\frac{\lambda^{1-s}}{s}\int_0^\infty t^{-s}e^{-\lambda t}dt.$$
Thus, you have
$$|\Gamma(-s)|\lambda^s=\frac{\lambda}{s}\int_0^\infty t^{-s}e^{-\lambda t}.dt$$
Therefore, what you try to prove is that
$$\int_0^\infty t^{-(s+1)}(1-e^{-\lambda t})dt=\frac{\lambda}{s}\int_0^\infty y^{-s}e^{-\lambda t}.dt$$
By doing by parts (you don't have your problem at $0$ anymore since you have the $1$ now): $f(t)=1-e^{-\lambda t}$ -> $f'(t) = \lambda e^{-\lambda t}$ and $g'(t)=t^{-(s+1)}$ -> $g(t) = \frac{t^{-s}}{-s}$, you find easily the previous formula.